# Nautilus (files) does not open any of my files

Tags: nautilus

Two days from now nautilus stopped opening any files. If I double click on a pdf nothing happens. The right button menu says "open with file viewer" but it does not work either. Only if I select "open with other application" the file opens.

I found this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1778069 but I think it is not my case. I do not have exo-utils installed

I am using ubuntu 20.10 updated.

Please, any help is great

Comment: I would open a terminal and run `nautilus` from there.  I'd hope messages will appear on *terminal* screen that will provide clues.  *FYI: I had a quick look at your listed bug, and you didn't mention running XFCE so I doubt the bug you mentioned relates*

Comment: in fact I am using plain Ubuntu with gnome. That's why I am not affected by the other bug. But your comment put me on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

Well thanks to guiverc help I found the culprit

I started nautilus from command line, then I clicked on a file and saw this:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: 09:03:37.960: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
WSL Interopability is disabled. Please enable it before using WSL.
grep: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop: No such file or directory
[error] WSL Interoperability is disabled. Please enable it before using WSL.
/usr/bin/wslview: line 214: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/reg.exe: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/wslview: line 305: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

I found that I had the `wslu` package (integration with windows 10). I do not remember installing that, but after uninstalling all works right again

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that Ubuntu 22.04 desktop files and folders were visible but did nothing when clicked. Also, `xdg-open ~` from Terminal gave errors similar to what you saw from Nautilus. The solution to both problems was the same: `sudo apt remove wslu`